# Setup Egg Error when trying to install Torchvision | Python and Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I'm trying to install PyTorch from: https://pytorch.org/

At this point, I've tried so many things and don't even remember, but I believe that I was finally able to get the first command

```
pip3 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-0.4.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

(I'm not sure if this is the one I eventually used) to work. I tried literally every windows combination and went through Github problems/comments to try and figure out what my issues were and how to fix it.

Then I tried to do the

```
pip3 install torchvision
```

which errored out and can be viewed below:

[image]

I searched many different links:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3884

https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/418

https://github.com/donnemartin/gitsome/issues/4

as some examples, regarding the issue. All suggested I use some variation of

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

which I have done. This hasn't helped my issue.

I'm using Windows 10, 64-bit

Python Version: 3.6.1

Anaconda Version: 4.2.0

I have updated my pip, numpy, and a lot of other things. At this point, I'm very confused. I appreciate the help.

Edit: At this point, like I said I don't even remember what I did to try and get the first command to work. running them all now I get the following:

Windows | Pip | 3.6 | 8 : `torch-0.4.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Windows | Pip | 3.6 | 9.0 : same

Windows | Pip | 3.6 | 9.2 : same

Windows | Pip | 3.6 | None : same

[image]

Running any of the `conda` commands gives me the same:

[image]

This is solved, I uninstalled my Anaconda and redownloaded it. Possible that I had a 32-bit, and it's now a corrected 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

try `pip3 install torchvision --no-deps`